# Dynamically detect and execute certain methods of an instance of a class

Tags: c++, rtti

In C++ (GCC g++), is there any means to determine at runtime all methods (or all public methods) of a given class, the names of which satisfy a certain pattern (i.e. have, eg, the string 'test' as part of their name), and then dynamically call them?

Comment: There is something really wrong in your design if you need to do this.You might want to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: no, C++ has no reflection...